# How do I determine which warlock pacts/patrons are best suited to which entities on Theros?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, religions-and-deities, theros

The *Mythic Odysseys of Theros* book lists, for each of the gods, the domains most associated to them, as well as a list of suggested classes for the god's champions.

Here is an example for [Athreos](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/moot/gods-of-theros#AthreossChampions) (p. 38):

> ### Athreos’s Champions
>
> **Alignment:** Usually lawful, often evil
> **Suggested Classes:** Cleric, monk, rogue, wizard
> **Suggested Cleric Domains:** Death, Grave (described in *Xanathar’s Guide to Everything*)
> **Suggested Backgrounds:** Hermit, sage, sailor, urchin

Obviously, this isn't an exhaustive list.

However, I haven't found a similar mapping for the warlock pacts or patrons. Does any information on this exist in the book (that I've missed)? If not, is such information available elsewhere?

Otherwise, how can I best determine which gods/monsters/entities make sense for each warlock pact and patron?

Comment: Inspired by [What archfey exist in Eberron lore that would make a suitable warlock patron?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170990)

Comment: I've edited your secondary question to ask more about the best way to determine what entity best matches each pact/patron, since a full assessment of "which gods/monsters/entities make sense for each warlock pact and patron?" itself would likely be both too broad and heavily opinion-based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Warlock options

I've provided my suggested options alongside the existing table that appears in Mythic Odyssey of Theros, and informed from my knowledge of the Magic the Gathering stories and setting (including, but not limited to the everpresent gods) released with the cards.

| Deity | Alignment | Suggested Cleric Domains | Suggested Patrons | Suggested Pacts | Common Symbol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Athreos, god of passage | LE | Death, Grave* | The Great Old One, The Undead, The Undying | Pact of the Talisman, Pact of the Tome | Crescent moon |
| Ephara, god of the polis | LN | Knowledge, Light | The Celestial, The Genie (Dao) | Pact of the Talisman, Pact of the Tome | Urn pouring water |
| Erebos, god of the dead | NE | Death, Trickery | The Fiend, The Hexblade, The Undead, The Undying | Pact of the Tome | Serene face |
| Heliod, god of the sun | LG | Light | The Celestial, The Hexblade | Pact of the Blade | Laurel crown |
| Iroas, god of victory | CG | War | The Celestial, The Fiend, The Hexblade | Pact of the Blade | Four-winged helmet |
| Karametra, god of harvests | NG | Life, Nature | The Archfey, The Genie (Dao) | Pact of the Blade, Pact of the Chain | Cornucopia |
| Keranos, god of storms | CN | Knowledge, Tempest | The Genie (Djinni), The Genie (Marid) | Pact of the Talisman, Pact of the Tome | Blue eye |
| Klothys, god of destiny | N | Knowledge, War | The Celestial, The Great Old One, The Hexblade | Pact of the Talisman, Pact of the Tome | Drop spindle |
| Kruphix, god of horizons | N | Knowledge, Trickery | The Great Old One | Pact of the Talisman, Pact of the Tome | Eight-pointed star |
| Mogis, god of slaughter | CE | War | The Fiend, The Genie (Efreeti), The Hexblade | Pact of the Blade | Four-horned bull’s head |
| Nylea, god of the hunt | NG | Nature | The Archfey | Pact of the Blade | Four arrows |
| Pharika, god of affliction | NE | Death, Knowledge, Life | The Archfey | Pact of the Chain, Pact of the Talisman | Snakes |
| Phenax, god of deception | CN | Trickery | The Undead, The Undying | Pact of the Talisman, Pact of the Tome | Winged golden mask |
| Purphoros, god of the forge | CN | Forge,* Knowledge | The Celestial, The Fiend, The Genie (Efreeti), The Hexblade | Pact of the Blade, Pact of the Talisman | Double crest |
| Thassa, god of the sea | N | Knowledge, Tempest | The Archfey, The Fathomless, The Genie (Marid) | Pact of the Blade | Waves |

#### Who are you actually reporting to?

The way that Warlock Patrons work is nebulous. The patron is typically not an actual god, even for The Celestial, in the sense that a cleric may worship a god. Often warlocks make pacts with intermediaries to gods or other unknowable entities, which may need some work to align with the setting of Theros.

These intermediaries are typically demigods of the listed deity, or powerful nymphs of the type associated with them. I have listed any exceptions that I can think of.

### Otherworldly Patrons

#### The Archfey

**Champion of:** *Karametra, Nylea, Pharika*

Any god with a connection to nature, or trickery that wasn't too heavily themed away from Fey was given this suggested patron. Karametra and Nylea fit this comfortably, whereas Pharika is only loosely connected.

#### The Celestial

**Champion of:** *Ephara, Heliod, Iroas, Klothys, Purphoros*

The archetypal gods with this suggested patron are Heliod and Ephara in that order, who embody ideas of 'justice', 'divinity' and 'holy light',in the way suggested by The Celestial. Iroas, Klothys and Purphoros either have a partial alignment to this theme, or some spin on it. Klothys dispenses a different kind of 'Justice', whereas Iroas and Purphoros match the 'Divine Light' themes of fire and creation.

#### The Fathomless

**Champion of:** *Thassa*
**Alternative Intermediaries**: Various sea monsters

This patron suggested so well fits the theme of Thassa, that no other Therosean deity gets this one. Not only does Thassa fit the nautical theme, she's also associated with giant sea monsters, so all the tentacle themed spells and abilities work perfectly.

#### The Fiend

**Champion of:** *Erebos, Iroas, Mogis, Purphoros*
**Alternative Intermediaries**: Powerful demons (which "are souls long consumed by hatred and other negative emotions" or powerful fire elementals, although they are very rare.

Fire + Luck = The Fiend. Iroas, Mogis and Purphoros all fit on the Fire side, as well as the resilience from Dark One's Blessing. Erebos is a slight outlyer, in not being fire themed, but the idea of the god of the underworld *not* being able to give somebody favour with Dark One's own luck didn't seem right to me.

#### The Genie

**Champion of:** *Ephara, Karametra, Keranos, Mogis, Purphoros, Thassa*

| Dao | Djinni | Efreeti | Marid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ephara, Karametra | Keranos | Mogis, Purphoros | Keranos, Thassa |
| Alseid, Dryad, or Oread nymph | Lightning elemental | Fire elemental, Oread nymph | Naiad nymph, Water elemental |

I've assigned these largely on the expanded spell list for each type of Genie. Ephara, because of her association with stonework, and Krametra because of her nature association have been lumped together under Dao. Keranos as the god of storms get both Djinni and Marid because both lists could work under the theme of 'storms'. Mogis and Purphoros get Efreeti because fire. End of. Thassa gets associated with Marid (and not Djinni) as she is much more about being *under*water than above it, but you could stretch to include her with Keranos under Djinni as well.

#### The Great Old One

**Champion of:** *Athreos, Klothys, Kruphix*

All these gods bring the notion of age and forbidden knowledge. Ephara doesn't fit, as she's possible the newest of the gods, and her knowledge is given freely. Thassa also doesn't fit, as the abilities of this patron are mind based, and she's more about smashing ships, calling on kraken and submerging cities

#### The Hexblade

**Champion of:** *Erebos, Heliod, Iroas, Klothys, Mogis, Purphoros*
**Alternative Intermediaries:** Any of the many artifacts associated with each of the listed gods

This one is split between the Hexblades affinity to blades (Heliod, Iroas, Mogis and Purphoros) and Hexes (Erebos, Klothys).

#### The Undead & The Undying

**Champion of:** *Athreos, Erebos, Phenax*
**Alternative Intermediaries:** Lampad nymph

These two are so similar, all gods with one patron suggestion share the other, that I've lumped these together. Quite simply, these gods have a strong association with death, the afterlife and/or the returned. Although Erebos does not like to see the denizens of the underworld rise again, the theme and mechanics seem close enough to smooth out the few rough edges lorewise.

### Pact Boons

#### Pact of the Blade

**Champion of:** *Heliod, Iroas, Karametra, Mogis, Nylea, Purphoros, Thassa*
All of these have an associated weapon (Godsend, Dekella) or type of weapon (Bident, Bows). Or just generally like weapons. Warlocks of Nylea who take this pact will want the Improved Pact Weapon invocation so as get bows.

#### Pact of the Chain

**Champion of:** *Karametra, Nylea, Pharika, Phenax*
These were tricky. Karametra and Nylea do have some association to animals, but only the Sprite (which could be rethemed as a minor [nymph](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Dryad#Theros)) or pseudodragon would seem to fit. Equally, retheming an pseudodragon, imp, quasit could work for Pharika (snake) or spider (Phenax)

#### Pact of the Talisman

**Champion of:** *Athreos, Ephara, Keranos, Klothys, Kruphix, Pharika, Phenax, Purphoros*
I've been very generous here. All the deities associated with artifacts or protection (a major Talisman theme) could potentially fit. Athreos with his coins, Ephara's amphora, Keranos (any, just invention themed), Klothys (drop spindle - her symbol), Pharika (vial of poison), Phenax (golden face mask) and Purphoros (any, just creation themed).

#### Pact of the Tome

**Champion of:** *Athreos, Ephara, Erebos, Keranos, Klothys, Kruphix, Phenax*
These are all associated with knowledge of some sort, or in the case of Erebos book keeping (i.e. recording the deeds of the dead). Unlike Thassa, these seem most associated to 'book knowledge' than *just* intuitive knowledge (Looking at you Thassa). Keranos and Klothys are edge cases, which almost didn't make the cut. They seem like the sort who's followers would have some inspiration strike them, and then *write it down*.

Answer (score 7):

Chapter 2 of *MOoT* gives suggested classes for the different gods. Warlock appears on 4 of those lists:

- [Klothys](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/moot/gods-of-theros#Klothys)
- [Mogis](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/moot/gods-of-theros#Mogis)
- [Pharika](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/moot/gods-of-theros#Pharika)
- [Phenax](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/moot/gods-of-theros#Phenax)

The section on each of these gods includes great detail about their history, and even includes a favor table that has some roleplay ideas for how your character has some relationship with the particular god. There doesn't seem to be any guidance beyond this for the warlock class, at least you've got some patrons to choose from.

Comment: Yup, I've seen that part of the book, so it's good to have that confirmed. Do you have anything else on top? Maybe a recommendation on what gods map to what patron/pact?

Comment: There's no further guidance in the book about that. It would just be an exercise in comparing what *Theros* says about each god to known information about the various patron subclasses. Such an exercise would largely be a matter of opinion, I think.

Comment: That's a real shame. I don't think adding detail would be too bad, as if you're familiar with the source material it should be a well informed opinion.

Comment: As time permits I can work toward making some calculated suggestions and add them to the answer, but I probably couldn't do it today. Maybe someone else will come along with a helpful answer to that effect before I can do so.

Answer (score 0):

#### The same way as every other D&D setting.

Like every other setting, Warlocks on Theros gain their powers from pacts with creatures for magical knowledge and power. Generally, gods don't produce Warlocks, they produce clerics or paladins, so we wouldn't expect the writeups for the various divinities to have Warlock pacts listed.

Instead, we'd have to look at the different creatures of Theros to see if they might qualify for the different types of Warlock Patrons. Generally, this can be divided along types: Fiends such as Night Hags or Abhorrent Overlords grant the Fiend Patron benefits, Celestials such as Unicorns or Archons grant the Celestial Patron benefits, Satyrs, Centaurs, and Nymphs might grant the Achfey Patron benefits, Undead such as Eidolons or the Returned grant the Undead Patron benefits, Aberrations such as Woe Striders would likely grant the benefitsof the Great Old One Patron, etc. Some are a bit less straightforward, but still fairly obvious: Krakens would fairly clearly grant the Patron benefit of the Fathomless, for instance, and a Typhon that could be bargained with would likely grant the Undead Patron benefits.

That said, looking over the list of monsters provided in Chapter 6: Friends and Foes of *Mythic Oddyseys of Theros*, I can't see any obvious creatures that would qualify for the Genie or Hexblade Patrons.